# My code crashes when calling my solve_chol() function using the lapack library

Tags: c, matlab

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int dpotrs(char *, int *, int *, double *, int *, double *, int *, int *);

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  double *C;
  int n, m, q;

  if (nrhs != 2 || nlhs > 1)                              /* check the         input */
    mexErrMsgTxt("Usage: X = solve_chol(R, B)");

  n = mxGetN(prhs[0]);

  if (n != mxGetM(prhs[0]))
    mexErrMsgTxt("Error: First argument matrix must be square");

  if (n != mxGetM(prhs[1]))
    mexErrMsgTxt("Error: First and second argument matrices must have same     number of rows");

  m = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, m, mxREAL); /* allocate space for output */
  C = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

  if (n==0) return;              /* if argument was empty matrix, do no more */
    memcpy(C,mxGetPr(prhs[1]),n*m*sizeof(double));   /* copy argument matrix */
    dpotrs("U", &n, &m, mxGetPr(prhs[0]), &n, C, &n, &q);   /* solve system */

  if (q > 0)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Error: illegal input to solve_chol");
}
```

Hello guys,

I am having a problem with this C-code. It is supposed to solve A matrix system `(Ax = B)` with `A` being symmetric, positive definite and already in upper triangular form?

I created this snippet to boost matlab performance, but unfortunately matlab crashes and some debugging showed that the problem is the call of `dpotrs()` towards the end of the script.
Can you see what the problem might be?

Information on `dpotrs()` can be found here: http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/routines/dpotrs.html

Would be great if you could help

Comment: Is the matrix positively definite? I am not sure if this causes a problem, or if this is handled, but this might be the source of the error. Try the function with a matrix you can be sure is positively definite and find out if the matrix causing the crash is.

Comment: `dpotrs("U", &n, &m, mxGetPr(prhs[0]), &n, C, &n, &q);` is this call rigth? The second argumetn is an integer, should it be just `n`? Why do you `C= mxGetPr(plhs[0]);` when later you memcopy `mxGetPr(prhs[1])`?

Comment: Looking at the code it seems as if @AnderBiguri is right. The call seems to take integers and not address of integers as input. The double arguments take arrays as argument which is about equivalent of taking a pointer. The reason you have integers n and m as input is for the function to know the length of the arrays. Further the first input should be a char and not a string (c-string == zero terminated array of chars). Further any reason you are using extern? Surely this function must be included in some header?

Comment: `warning: passing argument 2 of 'dpotrs' makes pointer from integer without a cast
     dpotrs('U', n, m, mxGetPr(prhs[0]), n, C, n, q);   /* solve system */ ` This is the warning I am getting when compiling the code without `&`. I am getting that error for positiont 2, 3, 5, 7 and 8.

Comment: @OliverEbrle As I said you have declared the function at the top of the compilation unit. There it is still declared as a pointer. You should probably make sure that the declaration is the same in all files. A compiler might find this bug but, but if you are unlucky it will miss it. You can try to edit the declaration and see if the warning disappear (and hope you will not get a linker error. In that case I would say you have a problem since this declaration then not match the function you are linked to)

Comment: Could you add something like `if(plhs[0]==NULL){mexErrMsgTxt("allocation failed");}` after `plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n, m, mxREAL);` ? This function can return NULL if memory allocation fails http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html .

Comment: Mh I discovered something weird, so the Code runs without problems an a 32 bit machine, but crashed on all 64 bit - there seems to be a memory problem somewhere? Anyone got an idea?